# Multiple form submissions prevented, but form not going through

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, button

PHP

```
<?php
    echo '<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
          <input type="submit" class="test1" name="myButton" value="Submit">
          <input type="submit" class="test1" name="myButton" value="Submit">
          <input type="submit" class="test1" name="myButton" value="Submit">
          </form>';

    if (isset($_POST['myButton'])) {echo 'Hey!';}
?>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkForm(form) // Submit button clicked
{
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("test1");
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

The above script allows me to disable all 3 buttons upon form submission so as to prevent multiple submissions before the page refreshes. However, the form submission does not go through (i.e. 'Hey' is not being echoed)

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried returning true at the end of the checkForm?  your onsubmit is expecting a return of true/false to know wither or not to cancel the request.  EDIT: also I may be wrong but I don't believe disabled form elements are sent across on the request.  You can check your network console for the request to confirm this.

Comment: Yes, I've just added a 'return true' at the end of the checkForm function. However, it still doesn't seem to be working.